# Where did Entity Framework connection strings move to?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio

I have an ASP.NET application that I have been creating with Visual Studio 2013 For Web. All of my connection strings for the Entity Framework have been stored in the application root Web.Config file.

I have migrated to Visual Studio 2015, and added a new Entity Framework model, and all of my Entity Framework connection strings have been relocated to some other file. The web application works fine on the test server, but I am having trouble in deployment since I cannot find the file that now contains these connection strings. Where did these move to?

Comment: AFAIK they didn't move anywhere.  They're still stored in the web.config.

Comment: @Amy - Yes, I just realized that somehow the file was restructured, and it appended all of the connection strings to a SQL connection string, in one long line. Thank you